# How to monkey-patch an internal private function in a python package?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

When using the package `pygal`, I have to change a utility function in `pygal.util` module. This function is called by other functions in other modules. How do I monkey-patch this function? Right now, I've edited the code in dist_packages but there must be a way to dynamically assign to this function?

The function is `pygal.util.is_major`. I tried to do it the following way:
`pygal.util.is_major = lambda x: False`
But it doesn't work. I think it's because the other modules in the package are importing this function into their local namespace. So me changing it has no effect since the older version of the function was already imported by the other modules into their local namespace.

Comment: What happens when you try to assign to the function directly? i.e. `pygal.util.whatever = new_func`

Comment: is the function you are monkey patching at the module level, class method, instance method?

Comment: @Narcolei That's not fool-proof, as any references held in some other namespace that were created before the monkey patch is applied will not be updated to the patched method, but straight assignment usually covers most scenarios, especially if you make sure to do the patching as early as possible in your program's execution.

Comment: @SilasRay Of course, that's why I posted a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @SilasRay The patching is the first step in the program

Comment: You could import the module, monkey-patch it, _then_ import any modules that import the patched modules. Do this the first thing in the program, right among import declarations.

Comment: You *could* try taking the function object and using `gc.get_referrers()` to loop over every reference to the function, then patching each object reference to point to your override method.  (Along with doing the simple assignment patching noted above to handle any future references created.)

Comment: @SilasRay good point. This can be avoided by using the garbage collector to track down references and update those as well. That's non trivial though. An alternative approach is to just switch out the function *body* - Plone uses this technique in security hotfixes. See [this discussion](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Monkey-patching-practices-of-current-Hotfix-Products-PloneHotfix20130618-1-1-td7566086.html) on how that back-fired.

Comment: @LukasGraf Non trivial to say the least.  Hence '*could*'.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason assigning to is_major doesn't work is because two other pygal modules import `is_major` into their local namepace before you assign to it.

The [pygal.graph.radar module](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/blob/643373c8d9dcc12db31a8dc5d40ff4f3c117c977/pygal/graph/radar.py#L28):

```
from pygal.util import deg, cached_property, compute_scale, is_major
```

And the [pygal.graph.graph module](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/blob/9ff557332af74496223bad41423c548836b2f858/pygal/graph/graph.py#L28):

```
from pygal.util import (
    is_major, truncate, reverse_text_len, get_texts_box, cut, rad, decorate)
```

If you can monkey path the `is_major` function before importing either of those modules, it should work. If you can't, you may be able to [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) the graph modules after monkey patching.

Something like this:

```
import pygal.util
import pygal.graph
import pygal.graph.radar

pygal.util.is_major = my_function
reload(pygal.graph)
reload(pygal.graph.radar)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in Python 3